# print to pdf with chrome headless doing nothing. No errors or anything

Tags: google-chrome, headless

I am using this command:

```
chrome --headless --print-to-pdf="C:\Users\rku172\Documents\workspace\test.pdf" www.google.com
```

No error occurs and no file is created. Sometimes randomly it creates the `pdf` file in the location out of maybe 10-20 attempts. But as such it is not working. I also tried the `--disable-gpu` flag but that didn't work either.

I am using `Chrome Version 70.0.3538.102` (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 7.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: nope.. had to leave it.